How to delete n no of rows from a table hybris
Huge data in my system is causing performance issues. So, I would like to delete 10000 records from Products table. Please let me know possible ways. Delete query with LIMIT is not working.

Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  Especially describe
what "is not working".

we can try below groovy script. Navigate to Console->scripting languages and toggle to commit mode.
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionExecutionBody;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorExecutionPolicy;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
 String query= "SELECT {PK} FROM {PRODUCT}";
 FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
 flexibleSearchQuery.setCount(10000); 
 SearchResult searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery);
 modelService.removeAll(searchResult.getResult());


An alternative to the proposed script in the other anwser, you could just use an impex to delete the relevant products if you know the PK of the products you want to remove.
REMOVE Product; PK[unique = true]

If you just want to remove 10k random products, you can run a select query to get those PK's through the HAC
